# How to make a list of new global variables after for loop? Python

Tags: python, list, global-variables

I have a function where each iteration creates a new variable. At the end of the loop I want to have a list of each of the variables so that I can call the values to columns in a data structure. Any thoughts? Here is my code now:
Thank you in advance

```
for o in range(len(tanks)):
    df2 = []
    for i in range(len(date)):
        l = df[((df[3] == tanks[o]) & (df[2] == date[i]))].index[0]
        df2.append(df.loc[l,6])
        globals()[f't{o}'] = df2
print(t0)
print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Comment: Don't use global variables, use a dictionary or list.

Comment: You're basically just using `globals()` as the dictionary.

Comment: But if you want a list of all the variables, use `variables.append(f't{o}')`

Comment: BTW, the assignment to globals shouldn't be in the nested loop, it should be after it.